# Using formset to display and validate many-to-many relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have following database schema

```py
class Ingredient(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Recipe(models.Model):
  # Many more fields that aren't important
  # ...
  ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='Measurement',
                                       blank=True, null=True)

class Measurement(models.Model):
  recipe     = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
  ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
  amount     = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now I want to display it inline as

```html
<!-- fields that are not important -->

<input type="text" name="ingredient" value="">
<input type="text" name="amount" value="">
```

so when a user types in the textbox ingredient and amount it saves a new entry to the Ingredient table and uses its id it the measurement table. Also I need to save some additional information in the Recipe table such as procedure and recipe title. How do I achieve such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Learn about [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) and [modelformsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets). You can use something like:

```
formset = modelformset_factory(Measurement)
```

**Warning** if there is a lot of recipes and ingredients, then rendering the select for ingredient and recipe for each form will be slow. A simple solution is to use an [autocomplete app](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/auto-complete/).

Example with django-autocomplete-light:

```
autocomplete_light.register(Ingredient, search_fields=['title'])
autocomplete_light.register(Recipe)

formset = modelformset_factory(Measurement, 
    form=autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(Measurement))
```